# How to distinguish a non-inflammatory tendinopathy (a.k.a tendinosis) from an inflammatory tendinopathy (a.k.a. tendinitis)?

Tags: tendinopathy

When suffering from some tendinopathy, how to distinguish whether the pain comes from a non-inflammatory tendinopathy (a.k.a tendinosis) or from an inflammatory tendinopathy (a.k.a. tendinitis)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, something falls under the classification of "inflammed" based on the following five criteria:

- Redness
- Swelling
- Heat
- Pain
- Loss of Function

If any of these apply to your tendinopathy, then it is probably tendinitis. Otherwise, it's probably non-inflammatory.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't non-inflammatory tendinopathy also case pain?

Comment: I think I was being misleading when I mentioned overuse in the previous question I answered. I quickly looked it up, tennis elbow is actually classified as a tendinosis. Essentially, pain is simply a sense that you feel when nociceptors are activated, whether you receive a cut or punch a wall.  Inflammation is simply an autoimmune reaction that involves pain, but it's not the only thing that can cause pain.